# Mint 17: Touchpad recognized as mouse

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, mouse, touchpad

I recently installed Mint 17 on my recently bought laptop, messing with the menus I noticed no options under the Touchpad tab on **Mouse and Touchpad** work, so I can't disable the touchpad while typing or mess with any touchpad related configuration. That led me to conclude Mint thinks my touchpad is a generic mouse. Is there any way I can force Mint to properly recognize the touchpad? I even tried `sudo modprobe -r psmouse`, as suggested on another question, no success though.

Running xinput returns this:

```
telmo@Telmo-LT ~ $ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL0651:00 06CB:2985                      id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Can you give a few more bits of info like: lsmod, lspci and lsusb?

Comment: What is the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: Here is the output for the four commands: http://pastebin.com/FSDh9bwv

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/721417/elantech-touchpad-recognized-as-ps-2-mouse-ubuntu-13-10 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/398568/psmouse-serio1-alps-unknown-alps-touchpad-in-a-lenovo-ideapad-flex-15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by updating my kernel to 3.17.1-031701. Before doing it, though, you might want to check your own kernel version by using `uname -a`.

For 32-bit systems:

```
$ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.17.1-utopic/linux-headers-3.17.1-031701_3.17.1-031701.201410150735_all.deb

$ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.17.1-utopic/linux-headers-3.17.1-031701-generic_3.17.1-031701.201410150735_i386.deb

$ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.17.1-utopic/linux-image-3.17.1-031701-generic_3.17.1-031701.201410150735_i386.deb

$ sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.17.1*.deb linux-image-3.17.1*.deb

sudo reboot
```

For 64-bit systems:

```
$ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.17.1-utopic/linux-headers-3.17.1-031701_3.17.1-031701.201410150735_all.deb

$ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.17.1-utopic/linux-headers-3.17.1-031701-generic_3.17.1-031701.201410150735_amd64.deb

$ wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.17.1-utopic/linux-image-3.17.1-031701-generic_3.17.1-031701.201410150735_amd64.deb

$ sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.17.1*.deb linux-image-3.17.1*.deb

sudo reboot
```

Comment: I followed the instructions, using a later kernel version from here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ - works great!